# How to install clang checker-275 and give me some example to configure Clang Scan-Build Plugin?

Tags: xcode4.5, clang, clang-static-analyzer

I have downloaded checker-275.tar.bz2 and try to use following command to configure but it throws error.

sudo ./Users/abc/Downloads/checker-275/set-xcode-analyzer --use-checker-build=$ABSOLUTE_PATH_TO_CLANG
Password:

error:
sudo: ./Users/abc/Downloads/checker-275/set-xcode-analyzer: command not found Mac-mini:~ aegon$ sudo ./Users/abc/Downloads/checker-275/set-xcode-analyzer --use-checker-build=$/Users/abc/Downloads/checker-275/bin/clang

I have followed this link for refernce..http://skabber.com/use-the-latest-version-of-clang/

Please help me to resolve this issue
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Please check this. I am also facing the same issue the i came to know that not only I but also many people facing the same issue. http://www.mail-archive.com/llvmbugs@cs.uiuc.edu/msg23874.html